# Creating several objects of the same class

Tags: java

I need to create 10 objects from my **Variable Class** but I'm getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
for(n=1;n<10;n++){
    variableTab[n]= "variable" +""+n;
    Variable variableTab[n] = new Variable();
    //System.out.println(variableTab[n]);
}
```

And the errors I have:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Variable to Variable[]
- Syntax error on token "n", delete this token
- Duplicate local variable `variableTab`

I don't know where is the problem because `variableTab[]` is a String Tab.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign data to an object that hasn't been created yet. Also, you shouldn't start at index 1. Arrays begin at index 0, so essentially, you are robbing yourself of extra space and making things harder on yourself by doing that. This also means that you are creating 9 objects, not 10. 
Use the implementation below.

```
Variable [] variableTab = new Variable [10];
for(n=0;n<10;n++){
    variableTab[n]= "variable" +""+n;

    //System.out.println(variableTab[n]);
}
```

**Update per comments:**

If you are trying to store the name of a object, you need to create a member variable to store that name in.

```
public class Variable {
   private String name; //This will be used to store the unique name of the object
   //Default constructor for our class
   Variable () {
      name = "";
   }

   //Constructor to initialize object with specific name
   Variable (String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   //We need a way to control when and how the name of an object is changed
   public setName (String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   //Since our "name" is only modifiable from inside the class, 
   //we need a way to access it from the program
   public String getName () {
      return name;
   }
}
```

This would be the proper way to setup a class. You can then control the data for each class in a more predictable way, since it is only able to be changed by calling the `setName` method, and we control how the data is retrieved from other sections of the program by creating the `getName` method.

Comment: I have tried it this way but I have an error ; cannot convert from String to Variable.

Comment: @Anatch You need to create a String member in the Variable class. You don't seem to have a solid understand of how classes work.

Comment: I just want to create 10 objects from the variable Class but with different names

Comment: Then you need to create a member inside that class to store the name you give it:   String name;    then store it using variableTab[n].name = "variable + " " + n;

Answer (score 0):

You might want to initialize your object first. If it is an array of objects that you're trying to create, do it this way:

```
Variable[] variableTab = new Variable[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign values to something that hasn't been created yet!
You're code should look like:

```
for(n=0;n<10;n++){
            Variable variableTab[n] = new Variable();
            variableTab[n]= "variable" +""+n;
            //System.out.println(variableTab[n]);
        }
```

Basically, you're trying to assign a value to something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This is still incorrect, by starting at n=1, you are only creating 9 objects instead of 10. Also, creating the objects inside the loop is more intensive than creating them outside of the loop.

Comment: oops, sorry! I'll fix it, missed that.